# Hibernate Postgres Batch Processing

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am running postgres sql 9.2.1 and for the application I am building I am using Hibernate 4.2.8. I have enabled all the necessary stuffs concerning the batch processing in the hibernate config file. Also in my pojo I am using the GenerationType.SEQUENCE for my ids since I am using POstgres sequence features.

However whenever I am doing bacth update it only executes one request and return this :

```
o.h.e.j.batch.internal.BatchingBatch - Executing batch size: 1
```

This is portion of my hibernate config file:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:testdb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_entity_mode">pojo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">40</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
```

Please assist me. I have done many searches so far but I have not come accross any that works for me.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here? You're trying to get batch updates - of what, why? PgJDBC its self doesn't really support batching, so even if you get Hibernate to send through statements in batches, if you're looking for performance gain you won't get much of it that way.

Comment: @CraigRinger : What I am trying to do is to perform bacth updates that update multiple rows of the same pojo. For instance activate users and so on...